# Need a simple preprocessor to operate on text file

Tags: python, perl, awk, text-files

I need to transform a text file that has modest expressions embedded into a new file without them.  Any expression-language is fine.  Example:

Input file:

```
days = 12
times_per_day = 10
extra = 2
The quick brown fox jumped $days * ($times_per_day + $extra) times over the lazy dog
```

Output file:

```
The quick brown fox jumped 144 times over the lazy dog
```

This needs to run on Windows.  Ideas I've thought of: use the C preprocessor (but I don't think it will statically evaluate all expressions?), or write my input file in perl/python/awk/etc (it won't be very readable, though).

I need this solved in 3-4 hours of effort, so I don't want to write a full parser.

Comment: Is the kind of text free or is it as your example shows? Perhaps `templating` is the keyword, which you are looking for. Something like ruby's ERB, xslate fpr PERL, Tenjin or whatever.

Comment: I think you are looking at much more than a few hours for this ...

Comment: 3-4 hours? Use Perl and be done with it.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think there must be an easy way; following leads from @ThomasJunk I suddenly realized `PHP` might be just the ticket: the command-line version does pretty much what I need, I think?!

Comment: I doubt it ... it wont actually evaluate the math ... just the variables

Comment: do you have control over the input? I think the perl solution is probably the way to go if you can get the input file in a different form

Comment: I can specify the input format and I have no security issues.  I could just `eval` each line from `python` maybe... or use `perl` though I don't know it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime one uses [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), it's almost by definition a hack job.

However, the following perl "one-liner" does get the job done in this specific instance:

```
perl -ne '!eof() ? eval "\$$_" : s/(?<!\S)(?=[[:punct:]\d]*\$)((?:\$\w+|[[:punct:]\d]+|\s+)+)(?!\S)/\@{[$1]}/g && print eval qq{"$_"};' fox.txt
```

Outputs:

```
The quick brown fox jumped 144 times over the lazy dog
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `!eof()`: Selective processing based on if we're at end of file.
- `eval "\$$_"`: Evaluate a line like `foo = 3` into `$foo = 3`
- `s/(?<!\S)(?=[[:punct:]\d]*\$)((?:\$\w+|[[:punct:]\d]+|\s+)+)(?!\S)/\@{[$1]}/g`

  Translate text like `string $foo * $bar end` into `string @{[$foo * $bar]} end`.
- `print eval qq{"$_"};`: print the evaluation of the final line.

Answer (score 4):

If you are proposing to use AWK, why does not GNU Bash fit? Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
days=12
times_per_day=10
extra=2
cat << EOF
The quick brown fox jumped $((days * (times_per_day + extra))) times over the lazy dog
EOF
```

Pretty readable, I hope.

If by some reason you want to get rid of `cat` (which is an external utility), that would not be a problem:

```
while read; do printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"; done << EOF
The quick brown fox jumped $((days * (times_per_day + extra))) times over the lazy dog
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python I would use a templating engine.  Jinja2 for example.  Code:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, Template


def main():
    environment = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'), trim_blocks=True)
    template = environment.get_template('test.tpl')
    print template.render()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Template file `test.tpl`:

```
{% set days = 12 %}
{% set times_per_day = 10 %}
{% set extra = 2 %}
The quick brown fox jumped {{days * (times_per_day + extra)}} times over the lazy dog.
```

Output:

```
The quick brown fox jumped 144 times over the lazy dog.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it would look using PHP:

```
<?
$days = 12;
$times_per_day = 10;
$extra = 2;
?>

The quick brown fox jumped <? echo $days * ($times_per_day + $extra); ?> times over the lazy dog
```

PHP on this input produces:

```
The quick brown fox jumped 144 times over the lazy dog
```

The only think I don't like is the need to include `echo` (and the difficulty getting PHP installed on Windows).

Comment: If you want to get rid of `echo` use `<?= $days * ($times_per_day + $extra); ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier if you separate the evaluation in the above expressions to substitutions. Finding an expression to evaluate within a sentence it pretty tedious, however, doing that on the right hand side of the `=` is a much simpler task. So something like the following is what can be done in a few minutes, and still can be used for building a very sophisticated language

```
data = '''days = 12
times_per_day = 10
extra = 2
total = $days * ($times_per_day + $extra)
The quick brown fox jumped $total times over the lazy dog
This is a new line that does nothing
The next line will reassign the variable total
total = $total + 1
Now the value of total is $total
'''.split('\n')

variables = {}

def replaceVariables(l):
    for k in variables: l = l.replace(k, variables[k])
    return l

def evalExpression(l): return str( eval( replaceVariables(l) )  )

for l in data:

    # if its a variable assignment, create a new variable 
    # this is also going to replace an old variable. 
    if '=' in l: 
        v, d = map(lambda m: m.strip(), l.split('='))
        variables['$' + v] = evalExpression(d) 
        continue

    # Otherwise just replace variables
    print replaceVariables(l)
```

For the above, this is the result:

```
In [13]: run test18
The quick brown fox jumped 144 times over the lazy dog
This is a new line that does nothing
The next line will reassign the variable total
Now the value of total is 145
```

Comment: It's not very robust. It fails with text lines containing `=`, it fails with expressions containing `=` (`a = b <= 42`), it fails with variables that are prefixes of other variables (`to = 23`, `total = 42`, `result: $total` may become `result: 23tal` instead of `result: 42`.